# Publishing or Deleting Beta Application from MarketPlace

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I have a "Private Beta Test" application on Marketplace. I want to publish "Public Marketplace" application. I cannot publish the application with the name what I already used in Beta. So I want either to remove beta and publish new public app or to upgrade beta to public app.

Till now I've "Ended Beta" on lifecycle page. Publish stage indicates "Ready to publish" checked and "Published" unchecked. What are my next steps? I cannot find any link or button to remove beta or publish beta as public application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to remove applications as of today. You'll need to leave it there, as unpublished.

And yes, it's annoying that Microsoft don't want to give us a delete button :(

Comment: Not exactly a solution but you can delete it after 90 days.

Comment: I can't. And I have *several* unpublished apps, that I can't remove, even it's been 4-5 months since they were published. It used to be possible on the AppHub, prior to the Mango update.